# RIDE tool not able to install on Ubuntu 20.4

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, automation, robotframework, robotframework-ide

still i'm facing RIDE installation issue on Ubuntu and I Have followed some instruction for download modules.

Please find the below issue:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/vkchlt0320/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/robotide/application/application.py", line 64, in OnInit
self._plugin_loader.enable_plugins()
File "/home/vkchlt0320/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/robotide/application/pluginloader.py", line 36, in enable_plugins
p.enable_on_startup()
File "/home/vkchlt0320/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/robotide/application/pluginconnector.py", line 52, in enable_on_startup
self.enable()
File "/home/vkchlt0320/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/robotide/application/pluginconnector.py", line 57, in enable
self._plugin.enable()
File "/home/vkchlt0320/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/robotide/contrib/testrunner/testrunnerplugin.py", line 225, in enable
self._add_tab_to_notebook()
File "/home/vkchlt0320/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/robotide/contrib/testrunner/testrunnerplugin.py", line 814, in _add_tab_to_notebook
self._output_panel = self._build_output_panel(self.panel)
File "/home/vkchlt0320/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/robotide/contrib/testrunner/testrunnerplugin.py", line 842, in _build_output_panel
self.show_message_log,
File "/home/vkchlt0320/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/robotide/pluginapi/plugin.py", line 136, in **getattr**
raise AttributeError("No attribute or settings with name '%s' found" % name)
AttributeError: No attribute or settings with name 'show_message_log' found
OnInit returned false, exiting...
Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
wx._core.wxAssertionError: C++ assertion "GetEventHandler() == this" failed at /tmp/pip-install-ojw8ebv0/wxPython/ext/wxWidgets/src/common/wincmn.cpp(477) in ~wxWindowBase(): any pushed event handlers must have been removed

Answer (score 0):

Your question does not reveal much of how you installed RIDE, and what instructions have you followed.

The reported error makes me suspect that you are not installing a release version of RIDE, but a development one.

To fix, you can try to edit the `~/.robotframework/ride/settings.cfg` file by adding to the section `[Plugins] [[Test Runner]]`
:

```
show_message_log = True
```

Comment: agian getting error like this ..............wx._core.wxAssertionError: C++ assertion "GetEventHandler() == this" failed at /tmp/pip-install-ojw8ebv0/wxPython/ext/wxWidgets/src/common/wincmn.cpp(477) in ~wxWindowBase(): any pushed event handlers must have been removed

Comment: That is a different error. You need to install wxPython from their site.